# Which gender should I write to

Tags: mobile, language, gender, verb

In my language (Hebrew) verbs can be appointed to either male or female, written in a bit different form. (there is no form referring to both).

**Which gender should I write "to"** (what form of verbs should I use)?

I'm developing a mobile app whose target market is Arab students from both genders.

I know of 2 options (please suggest others if you know of them):

1. Writing both - I think this gets it messy and not very user friendly (long texts on button etc.) example: `... form1/form2 ...`
2. Show a message when app is opened saying that all texts were written for the male/female gender for convenience and that it does not mean anything (the app is for both).

Comment: What choices do other Hebrew software programs use? This question is very culture/language specific and answers by native english speakers are not likely to be helpful.

Comment: There's a third option you haven't listed.  Use one gender consistently (as in option 2), but don't interrupt the user's workflow by displaying the message when the app starts.  Instead just place the explanation in a supplementary help page.

Comment: 1) Wait for [this proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/36772/hebrew-language-usage) to enter public beta; 2) Ask there :)

Comment: Technically there is no such word in English for third person. *you* is often used if directing at one person, if there is a Hebrew equivalent. For third party conversations however younger writers generally replace the formal he / she with "they" and there have even been proposals to standardize on a singular third person noun such as **hu** to follow the old grammar rules of he / she but not be sex-specific

Comment: Look at this answer http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/28180/can-you-sacrifice-grammar-to-keep-instructions-simple-specifically-when-using-a/28192#28192

Comment: Matching what other Hebrew software does is going to be the best option by far. We can give you options of what we would do in that situation, but even our best ideas will be wrong if it doesn't match what other software does, if there is any sort of standard.

Comment: @AthomSfere There is most definitely a third person pronoun in English.  "They" is the third person singular and plural form.

Comment: @JohnGB I agree that should be the case, but every English grammar teacher I have ever had or known would not accept it. This article starts with some of the arguments I have seen again and again although the problem is much older than Twitter http://www.nytimes.com/2009/07/26/magazine/26FOB-onlanguage-t.html?_r=0 Also, another good article: http://www.theatlanticwire.com/entertainment/2013/01/singular-their-affront-good-writing/61137/

Comment: @AthomSfere It's used in most of the English speaking world, and is universally understood.  That is enough for me.  If some grammar teachers have a problem, they can use something else, but every reference I have seen uses it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 2. Better to be consistent in your writing, and tell the user what you're doing and why. I would choose the default gender based on other Hebrew writings that your users may have been exposed to.

Comment: Most hebrew writings use the male gender. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Recently I happened to attend a training on Plain English in which I asked my trainer the same question. My point was that writing he/she together to mention my user is not cool and repetitive use of he/she rather reduces the impact actual point which I am making. Also a "/" (slash) in the writing looks ugly as this is diagonal character and rest of the letters are written vertically straight.

My trainer mentioned following solutions to gender issue.

- use gender-neutral subject "the user" and avoid using he/she altogether
- if you had to pick a gender, pick one of the two and stick to it within an article But write to the other gender in your next article and put such articles together to be seen as unbiased.
- If not sure which gender to use, using she is slightly safer to use than he.

Comment: I know this is a question about the Hebrew language, however, as an native English speaker, I must disagree with the last bullet. Using "she" rather than "he" in a gender neutral context still stands out as odd. As Strunk and White put it: 

    "The use of ‘he’ as a pronoun for nouns embracing both genders is a simple, practical convention rooted in the beginnings of the English language. No one need fear to use ‘he’ if common sense supports it."

Comment: Hi Hamilton. Two thoughts here. Use of "he" may not "save"  us as gender addressing issues were born when use of "he" the convention. Second, as a standard practice in South Asia where I am from and where English is taught as second language, it is common practice to use "she" whenever gender is unknown. BUT I agree use of "she" stands out odd, yet it is less "provocative" to gender conscious section and you are likely to receive less criticism than otherwise. So even though it reads odd, it is politically more accurate than "he".

Comment: Interesting info. The "gender conscious section" does get up in arms over the use of he, however there is also a section that sees the use of she over he as pandering and silly prescriptivism. No matter which pronoun you use some people will be off put, so from a usability standpoint I still strongly agree with your first bullet in an effort to avoid the quagmire of gender specific pronouns altogether.

Comment: @hhamilton I agree, I see it as pandering myself. Although not at all sexist, I do take issue with pandering. It is illogical to be upset about generalizing with *he* and instead using *she*. Its the same problem and solves nothing, other than reading odd and breaking old grammar rules.

Comment: "Man is a mammal who gives birth to live young and suckles them at his breast." -- the classic example of why the generic use of the masculine form is (or can be) nonsense.

Comment: It is becoming a widespread convention to use they, their, them and to refer to users/people in the plural.

Comment: @YvonneAburrow I have started to see that referred to as [singular they](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they).

Comment: Yes, I sometimes refer to it as that (but the thing is, you don't say "they is", you continue to say "they are"). The pronoun "you" used to be plural in many languages until it was used as the polite form - and in some languages (e.g. German) the polite form of "you" is "they"! Pronouns are more fluid than many people realise.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no gender-neutral option in Hebrew, I would suggest asking the user whether they would prefer form1 or form2, and toggling all instances where they occur to the preferred option (unless it modifies your verb-endings, in which case, that makes it a lot of work).

Is there an option in Hebrew to use a gender-neutral plural form?  (like we do in English with they, them, their)

Answer (score -5):

Just write around the gender issue. It makes translation easier, too.

Is it impossible to avoid using gender pronouns? I can't think of an example where you **have** to use gender pronouns and cannot use something gender neutral like "User".

Comment: In hebrew, if you want to say "Send", you have 2 forms, one for male and one for female